# Titanium Appcelerator Running error on iOS 9.2

Tags: iphone, sdk, titanium, appcelerator, ios9.2

Device: iPhone 5 (Model A1429)
iOS version: 9.2 (13C75)
Titanium SDK: 4.0.0.GA

When I tried to run/distribute my app, I faced this error messages

> [ERROR] :  ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> [ERROR] :  The following build commands failed:
>
> [ERROR] :     Ld build/iVirtue.build/Debug-iphoneos/iVirtue.build/Objects-normal/arm64/iVirtue normal arm64
>
> [ERROR] :  (1 failure)

The warning in TiApp Editor > Deployment Targets said

> iOS development requires [5.0, 9.0) but you have 9.2

Initially, when I haven't updated my Titanium Studio and my iOS version, the app was running perfectly. Please help.

Comment: Thank you, i already edited. Is it exactly what you had in mind?

Comment: Create a new project and try to run. If it works fine then their is a issue with the Xcode configuration in your project.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't clearly explain it before. The app i made was made on Titanium Studio, so installed the Appcelerator Studio and have the app exported. Now, it's working well. Thank you all, now i can close this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the Titanium SDK to the latest 5.1.2.GA & all other components as well, because as you said that the app was working fine before so it is something related to the updates.

Use Titanium Studio to update everything available.

Comment: I found the update code from builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#5_1_X . I am now trying to make it works by installing it with help>Titanium SDK and then trying to install iPhone in deployment target from TiApp Editor, but there was error message: An internal error occurred during: "Configuring SDK".
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem in your run configuration (or tiapp.xml). I suggest you first delete the run configuration, run the app again to define a new run configuration. Also check tiapp.xml to see if you have any references to iOS version?

You should also clean your project prior to running it after having deleted the run configuration :-)

/John

Comment: I found the update code from builds.appcelerator.com.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html#5_1_X . I am now trying to make it works by installing it with help>Titanium SDK and then trying to install iPhone in deployment target from TiApp Editor, but there was error message: An internal error occurred during: "Configuring SDK". java.lang.NullPointerException